# Проблема с функцией imagecopyresized: Invalid image dimensions

Tags: изображения, php

**Проблема с функцией imagecopyresized, пишет Invalid image dimensions**

```
$filename = "result.jpg";
$size = getimagesize("http://kvonosan.webege.com/rasta_files/rastamanka.jpg");
$image_p = imagecreatefromjpeg("http://kvonosan.webege.com/rasta_files/rastamanka.jpg");
$image_z = imagecreatefromjpeg("http://kvonosan.webege.com/rastamanki/rastamanka1.jpg");
imageAlphaBlending($image_z, false);
imageSaveAlpha($image_z,true);

if (!imagecopyresized($image_p, $image_z, 70, 120, 0, 0, 270, 320, $size["width"], $size["height"]))
{
 echo "error";
}
imagejpeg($image_z, $filename);
imagedestroy($image_z);
imagedestroy($image_p);
```

Comment: А где уверенность в том, что тот самый сайт не защищен от "вытягивания" картинок и вместо картинки скрипт получает нечто другое типа Err-403?
Попытайтесь подставить каринку с собственного хостинга из-под своей директории, где и расположен собственно скрипт.

Comment: это мой хостинг

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, во-первых, если распечатать

```
print_r($size);
```

то получим

```
Array ( [0] => 400 [1] => 600 [2] => 2 [3] => width="400" height="600" [bits] => 8 [channels] => 3 [mime] => image/jpeg )
```

где явно видно, что элементов `$size["width"]` и `$size["height"]` не существует, а надо использовать `$size[0]` и `$size[1]`.

И во-вторых, надо в конце использовать `resource $dst_image`, т.е. `$image_p`, а не `$image_z`

```
imagejpeg($image_p, $filename);
```

И еще: если картинки лежат на вашем же хостинге, то не надо их вызывать через URL - лучше брать относительным путем, с файловой системы, т.е.

```
$image_p = imagecreatefromjpeg("/rasta_files/rastamanka.jpg");
```

Comment: спасибо вы правы.